# Make Bash handle variables like Batch

Tags: bash, batch-file

I have a Batch script with more than 7000 lines (A year of hard work) and i want to convert it to Bash. But it's impossible. Can Bash *(somehow)* handle variables, inputs, and **if** lile **Batch**? I need a code like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Insert solution here
set /p name=My name is 
echo Nice to meet you %name%
```

Comment: I bet if you searched the internet you could find a really nice table of what the .BAT script equivalent is in BASH.  All kinds of articles have been written about it over the past two decades.

Comment: If Stack Overflow Documentation still existed, I could point you to the page I wrote for this. Unfortunately, that page no longer exists. Fortunately, I also posted the chart to reddit about a year ago: https://www.reddit.com/r/scripting/comments/ftj7pm/bash_tutorialguide_for_batch_programmer_ie/fm7t9tq/?context=3

Comment: You were already provided with some advice in [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68920185), with a different account name! Instead of creating multiple accounts here, would it not have made more sense to edit your previous question such that it was a specific and on topic issue, so that you could have received focused help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not impossible. Use the `read` command.

```
read -p "My name is " name
echo "Nice to meet you $name"
```